# How can you completely remove an old deleted field?

Tags: 8, entities, database

After deploying a Drupal 8 site to a new server, we have the problem of an old deleted field being remembered by some subsystem or other, leading to this error being thrown on whenever cron runs:

```
Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:
1146 Table 'drupal8_neu_default.field_deleted_data_1c89727af8' doesn't exist:
SELECT DISTINCT t.entity_id AS entity_id
FROM {field_deleted_data_1c89727af8} t
WHERE  (bundle = :db_condition_placeholder_0)
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0; Array
(
    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => video
)
in
Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->readFieldItemsToPurge()
(line 1546 of /srv/www/neu.default.ch/builds/v1.0.0-alpha.7/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
```

I've spelunked all over the database, and I can't figure out where to expunge the reference to this long-dead table. It's not mentioned in `config` and the `field_config` table we knew from Drupal 7 is long gone. It's also not in the exported configuration.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is in the state/key_value table, with the keys field.field.deleted field.storage.deleted.

To find them, run this sql:

```
select * from key_value where name = "field.field.deleted" or name = "field.storage.deleted"
```

See \Drupal\field\FieldConfigStorage::loadByProperties() and \Drupal\field\FieldStorageConfigStorage::loadByProperties()

Comment: ... and then going ahead and deleting those is fair game, or poses what risk...? Seemed to be ok to nix the values from that table, but who knows(!)

Answer (score 8):

Execute this to remove deleted field(s), pending deletion:

```
drush php-eval 'field_purge_batch(1000);'
```

Comment: great, it's the right command for Drupal 7 too

Comment: This quickly generates the error seen be the OP, but does not resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could resolve this was to create the missing table, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE `field_deleted_data_XXX` (   
`bundle` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`revision_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`langcode` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`content_translation_source_value` varchar(12) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`langcode`),
KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`) );
```

Replacing `XXX` with the code that follows `field_deleted_data_` in the error message.  Then run:

```
drush php-eval 'field_purge_batch(1000);'
```

This may generate the error with a new code.  I had to go through the process 3 times, but eventually it resolved the error.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you every one for your answers that allowed me to build the following (imperfect) solution.

List deleted fields waiting to be purged:

```bash
drush php:eval "var_dump(\Drupal::state()->get('field.storage.deleted'))"
```

If the result is not an empty array, create the missing `field_deleted_data_*` tables:

```bash
drush php:eval '$deleted_field_storage_configs = \Drupal::state()->get("field.storage.deleted");
$database = \Drupal::database();

foreach($deleted_field_storage_configs as $field_storage_config) {
  $table_name = "field_deleted_data_" . substr(hash("sha256", $field_storage_config->getUniqueStorageIdentifier()), 0, 10);

  $sql_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . $table_name . "` (
    `bundle` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '\'\'',
    `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\''0'\'',
    `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `revision_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `langcode` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL DEFAULT '\'\'',
    `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `content_translation_source_value` varchar(12) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`langcode`),
    KEY `bundle` (`bundle`),
    KEY `revision_id` (`revision_id`) );";

  $database->query($sql_query);
}
'
```

Remove the fields:

```bash
vendor/bin/drush php-eval 'field_purge_batch(1000);'
```

Check that no more fields are waiting to be purged:

```bash
drush php:eval "var_dump(\Drupal::state()->get('field.storage.deleted'))"
```

You can now safely remove `field_deleted_data_*` tables that are still present in the Drupal database.

To perfect this solution:

I based the table name computation on the code of the SqlContentEntityStorage::readFieldItemsToPurge() method.

The better way to do this would be to find a way to get the SqlContentEntityStorage and field storage definition to have the good version of table name computation:

```php
$storage_definition = $field_definition->getFieldStorageDefinition();
$table_mapping = $this->getTableMapping();
$table_name = $table_mapping->getDedicatedDataTableName($storage_definition, $storage_definition->isDeleted());
```

Comment: This solution was the most effective and efficient for me